# All subdomains are redirecting to main domain

Tags: dns, redirection

I transferred my website to a new server about 2 days ago.
I changed my Domain's NSs...
After that, Now, all of my subdomains are showing exactly what my main domain is showing!
have a look:
http://aftab.cc
http://st.aftab.cc
http://gallery.aftab.cc

Could you please help me?

Comment: Did you enter entries for the subdomains on the name server?

Comment: What do you mean? (I don't have access to the server. I'm just a user with CPanel)

Comment: See @RedGrittyBrick's answer below. Essentially unless you want to configure your webserver for sub-domains you would need DNS entries on the DNS Server for each.

Answer (score 1):

When a webserver like Apache receives a HTTP request for a web-site domain that it isn't configured for, it will return the contents for the first website that is in it's configuration.

(or a 404 response if the part of the URL after the hostname doesn't exist in the default site)

So probably the webserver isn't correctly configured.

Configuring domains in DNS is a separate action from configuring sites (with domain-names) in a web-server. Details depend on your hosting service.

---

Update:

### DNS

Here's an example DNS zone file

```
 www.example.com   IN   A   203.0.113.5
 www.example.org   IN   A   203.0.113.5
```

Your domain hosting provider will have a point and click GUI for you to add these records, you don't have to do it using a text editor. However exactly what the GUI tools look like, and how to use them, depend on exactly which domain hosting service you are using.

In the case of the problem you describe, these records are probably set up correctly, you want to host both example.com and example.org on the same server.

### HTTPD

Here's an [example configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for Apache HTTPD

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

If the second `<VirtualHost>` clause (for example.**org**) was omitted, Apache would serve up the page for example.com if you asked it for example.org. (actually it's been a while since I tested this but I expect it is still so).

Your hosting company's Control-Panel will have a point and click GUI that will cause the appropriate sections to be added to the HTTPD configuration file for you (you don't have to edit this textual configuration file using a text editor).

If your web-hosting company uses Nginx or IIS instead of Apache HTTPD, the config file may look completely different. The design and operation of the configuration GUI depends on your exact hosting provider, there are too many variations to cover them all here.

---

I believe aftab.cc is hosted by your-server.de who use Apache HTTPD and cPanel, If you google for "How to add a site to a cPanel hosting plan" you should find some useful videos and other tutorial material. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but how can they solve the problem? I mean what should they do? I want to send them this page to study and maybe solve the problem. (I'm guessing they don't know how to solve the problem!)

Comment: @Hamid: See updates. As I originally said, what you do depends on exactly which control-panel and httpd software your hosting service uses. They vary a lot, I can't cover all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was discovered!!
You may not believe but it seems that it is a bug in CPanel, when you transfer a website to a new server, sometimes all subdomains are added as a Parked Domain!!!!
You have to go to Parked domain and remove all of them and if it is needed you should remove all subdomains and create them again!!

I just remembered when we transferred our website about 7 years ago, I faced to this problem but I couldn't understand how our hosting solved the problem! but now they told me the problem...

Anyway, I hope this topic would be useful for future and I hope CPanel team review their codes and cover the bug!

Thanks for your help ;)